# Laptop becomes really slow when using dedicated GPU on battery

Tags: battery, nvidia-prime

I have Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and nvidia 1650 dedicated graphics (and intel 630 uhd integrated). When the laptop is plugged in, it runs really fast and has no problems, but as long as I unplug the charger, the system becomes really slow and unusable. The only way to "fix" this is enable "powersaving mode" in Prime profiles of my nvidia driver (currently 435, latest LTS). Rebooting back to nvidia performance mode makes the pc unusable again (and drains a lot of battery, literally for nothing).

CPU: `Model name:          Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-9750H CPU @ 2.60GHz`

`lspci` says:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 8th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 07)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 07)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 3e9b
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 07)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
00:12.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Thermal Controller (rev 10)
00:13.0 Serial controller: Intel Corporation Device a37c (rev 10)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH USB 3.1 xHCI Host Controller (rev 10)
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Shared SRAM (rev 10)
00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless-AC 9560 [Jefferson Peak] (rev 10)
00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device a368 (rev 10)
00:15.1 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device a369 (rev 10)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH HECI Controller (rev 10)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Device a353 (rev 10)
00:1b.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device a340 (rev f0)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port 9 (rev f0)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device a30d (rev 10)
00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH cAVS (rev 10)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH SMBus Controller (rev 10)
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH SPI Controller (rev 10)
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1f91 (rev a1)
3b:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Device a809
```

Edit: tried updating the drivers to `440.64`, did not really help

Edit 2: more info:

```
(base) katsarov@Dell-Inspiron-7590-Katsarov:~$ grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/*
/sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/hwp_dynamic_boost:0
/sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/max_perf_pct:100
/sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/min_perf_pct:17
/sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/no_turbo:0
/sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/num_pstates:38
/sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/status:active
/sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/turbo_pct:50
(base) katsarov@Dell-Inspiron-7590-Katsarov:~$ grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/*
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/affected_cpus:0
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/base_frequency:2600000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/cpuinfo_max_freq:4500000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/cpuinfo_min_freq:800000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/cpuinfo_transition_latency:0
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/energy_performance_available_preferences:default performance balance_performance balance_power power 
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/energy_performance_preference:balance_performance
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/related_cpus:0
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_available_governors:performance powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq:800101
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_driver:intel_pstate
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor:powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq:4500000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_min_freq:800000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_setspeed:<unsupported>
```

Edit #3: I add outputs from `turbostat` with and without dedicated graphics (tried maxing the pc out and open everything I can, on dedicated gpu the pc was struggling opening 2 pages with chrome)

https://pastebin.com/gQc0PcBN <- With integrated graphics

https://pastebin.com/Dzx52pLG <- With dedicated graphics

Comment: What is the LapTop brand? What do you get for `grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/*` and `grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/*` and is anything different between battery and plugged in?

Comment: I will add it in the question info, thanks. It is the same when plugged in. The laptop is slow however when prime profile is nvidia, intel is fine

Comment: Sometimes Dell limits things based on powered or battery. Suggest to monitor `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq` under both conditions. Force a 100 % load on one CPU to observe max frequency. Run this to monitor things `sudo turbostat --Summary --show --quiet Busy%,Bzy_MHz,PkgTmp,PkgWatt,GFXWatt,IRQ --interval 15` (I run it always).

Comment: `sudo: turbostat: command not found` hm okay. It happens only with the dedicated gpu enabled. When I use the integrated, everything is fine. Using the dedicated also makes pages load slower.. everything runs basically slower.

Comment: It seems that Dell indeed trottles this from the bios. Many other Dell users have reported this as well

Comment: turbostat is in the linux-tools-common package. A very useful tool.

Comment: I installed it and put the info in the question, thanks

Comment: hmmm... maximum CPU frequency seems much less for the integrated case, not the dedicated case. Dedicated case much hotter.